# What can we do to use chat for community-building?

Tags: discussion, chat

I've been talking with the mods and we've come to the conclusion that it's time we liven up the community chat.

As you all (I hope) know, we have the Phil.SE chat rooms, including the general chat room **"Symposium"**. Unfortunately, as a community we aren't using the chat as often as I think we want to. And, when we do, it's often to "move comments to chat", and not to properly talk about what we really like to talk. In order to explain a bit more, I'd like to go through the meaning of the chat rooms.

Stack Exchange, as a network, hosts a Q&A type of forums. That is well known to everyone in this community. But SE understood that many things we, as a community, want to talk about, doesn't fit the Q&A style. Here comes chat rooms.

Granted, the chat rooms doesn't fit to every type of discussions - especially long ones, when you'd want to write a comment that's longer than the character limit. But nonetheless, it's perfectly fine for "normal" chit-chating, or even bigger, community-wide discussions and "meetups".

Now after going through the cons and pros of the chat rooms, let's go through what we've gathered here for: **what do we want to do, community-wide, with the chat rooms**. This is a question that's open for every single one of us, anyone who'd like to propose community events, dedicated chat rooms for specific topics, and anything that pops to your mind that you think utilizes the chat rooms best is acceptable.

**This Meta question is open for everyone to participate and answer their own suggestions**. We will try to make as many of these suggestions come to realization as we can. You can also voice your concerns in the comments, or any sub-suggestions that you may have for the answers (for example: I may suggest "let's make history of philosophy quizzes", and someone may suggest in the comment "we can make community trophies for the winners", or anything else you can think of).

After deciding which suggestions we'll make, if it's an event that requires a time phrame we'll open up a meta question asking for people to vote when they think the event should happen. We'll try to pick a date where as many of the members would be able to participate.

That's it, now go ahead and suggest to your heart's content!

**Of course, following the spirit of the post, there is also a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84160/utilizing-chat) you can use for suggestions and discussions.**

Answer (score 1):

To make a start, I would like to suggest that if you are an active user on this site, and you are online and have some time at your hands:

### Simply have a tab open with [the Symposium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium) and say "Hi".

If two decades of experience with the internet are any indication, this should actually help a big deal to come into contact on a more personal level and have chats about basically anything (that does not violate any rules ;) ).